# Disallow user registration/checkout via Hotmail/Yahoo

Tags: users, user-registration

Hope someone can help or point me in the right direction...

I'm looking to disable user registration on my  website for users trying to register with Hotmail and Yahoo email addresses. It would also be a good idea to also provide a suitable error message to the user too, any ideas on how I'd go about doing this? I've seen the `user_register` hook, but not sure where to start...?

All help appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Can I ask why you want to do this? A lot of people use yahoo/hotmail

Comment: Yes, our customers are businesses and businesses don't tend to use Hotmail/Yahoo email addresses...

Comment: Anyone have any idea...?